# Error trying to send email with SendGrid in a VM ubuntu in Azure

Tags: php, azure, ubuntu, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

SendGrid Azure 
I have a VM with Ubuntu that I created 2 year ago in azure, In which I can send email throw SendGrind with no problems.

Now I create an other VM with ubuntu, I copied the same code that I have in the other server and nothing works. I get an 500 error. 
If I commented the next line the error is gone but I don't know why there is a problem:

```
 $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
```

I don't remember if I need to install something in the server, I hope you have some ideas.

```
require("../sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");
//If not using Composer, uncomment the above line
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
$email->setFrom("xxxxx@gmail.com", "Example User");
$email->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addTo("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "Example User");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent("text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>");
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('the-key'));
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode(). "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
 } catch (Exception $e) {
     echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the first VM you referrence is two years old, it's possible you are using the standard port **25** to talk to SendGrid.  Starting on November 15th, 2017, sending outbound email directly to external domains (such as outlook.com, gmail.com) from a Virtual machine (VM) will be made available only to certain subscription types. Outbound SMTP connections using TCP port 25 (primarily used for unauthenticated e-mail delivery) will be blocked for most new subscriptions (more details below).

More details here on options:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2017/11/15/enhanced-azure-security-for-sending-emails-november-2017-update/